# Transposing Column Data into Row Data SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data that looks like this in an SQL table.

```
[ID],[SettleDate],[Curr1],[Curr2][Quantity1],[Quantity2],[CashAmount1],[CashAmount2]
```

The issue i have, i need to create 2 records from this data (all information from 1 and all information of 2). Example below.

```
[ID],[SettleDate],[Curr1],[Quantity1],[CashAmount1]
[ID],[SettleDate],[Curr2],[Quantity2],[CashAmount2]
```

Does anyone have an ideas how to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard (ie cross-RDBMS) solution for this is to use `union`:

```
select ID, SettleDate, Curr1, Quantity1, CashAmount1 from mytable
union all select ID, SettleDate, Curr2, Quantity2, CashAmount2 from mytable
```

Depending on your RBDMS, neater solutions might be available.

Comment: Thanks guys! really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Just another option.  The ItemNbr 1/2 is just to maintain which element.

```
 Select A.[ID]
       ,A.[SettleDate]
       ,B.*
  From  YourTable A
  Cross Apply ( values (1,[Curr1],[Quantity1],[CashAmount1])
                      ,(2,[Curr2],[Quantity2],[CashAmount2])
              ) B{ItemNbr,Curr,Quantity,CashAmount)
```

Comment: Thanks guys! really helpful